# How come most people are on Android 4.1 and not 4.2 or 4.3?

Tags: android

I am seeing some errors on Android 4.3 which by numbers is the highest version, but then I see most of my installs are on 4.1, 4.0.3-4.0.4, 4.2 is the 3rd by installs.

So what is wrong with 4.3 (Jellybean)? I have some crashes that happen on it, but not other versions. Was Jellybean some buggy Android verison? Or what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're a power user who installs your own ROMs, you are at the whim of the manufacturer to get OS updates.  In many cases they have not been prompt to update (or even want to update at all).

This chart gives a good layout of what versions people are using in general on Android: http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Without a nexus you dont get vanilla stock android over the air OS or updates.

Some manufactures take a long time to update their phones and some phones from same manufacturer dont get updated.  So so phones cant actually get the latest OS without custom rom etc.   Even some top phones released today are not 4.3, and probably never will.